# Git branch ahead of master and can't checkout master

Tags: git

I have an extremely simple repository. I made two commits with SourceTree. Then created a branch `working`. I made a commit on `working`.

[image: Situation]

I now want to merge it back into master so that I have a linear history. I am new to git and now sure what I'm doing wrong. At this point I can't checkout master as I get the error **even though I have no working copy changes**:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false checkout master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    web/index.html
    web/js.js
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

Right clicking on master branch/revision and clicking `merge` or `rebase` has no effect. What did I do wrong? What is the "standard" workflow I should be using?

EDIT: I think what I should be doing is `checkout master; merge working`, but I am not sure why I cannot checkout master.

EDIT2: Looking at the `working` branch/commit(it is indeed committed, not just staged), I see the exact files that it is complaining about in the error.

EDIT3: I see an error when doing `git status`:

```
$ git status
web/index.html: Permission denied
web/js.js: Permission denied
# On branch working
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: Git differs with your assertion that you have no working code changes.  If you trust yourself more than you do Git, then attempt to do a reset --HARD on `working`.

Comment: You can see by the checkmark that I have no working copy changes. Unless the fact that there are changes in `working` counts as working copy changes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure what was going on. I had a web server running that was serving those files, as well as having them open in Notepad++. After shutting down the web server the graph in SourceTree refreshed to show that there are uncommitted changes of those two files being deleted. I'm not sure why they were deleted. After throwing away those changes I was able to checkout master and merge working.

Answer (score 0):

What the error message is stating is that you currently have changes that are staged to be commited on `working` which would be lost if you switched your branch to `master`.

- If I don't want to commit the changes, then I would [**stash**](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing) them instead.  This creates a stack of changesets which I could go back and apply at any time I wanted.
- If I want to commit my changes, then merge the branches together, then it's a pretty straightforward (and typical) commit, after which I can then switch to `master` and perform a `git merge working`.
- If I *really* don't think I made any changes, then I would do a `reset --hard HEAD`, and ensure that there were no changes staged.